# Assign UITableView Cell label text from Swift dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, indexpath

I am trying to get a value from a swift dictionary to display as cell texts. I am getting error:

> Type 'Any' has no subscript members

```
cell.audioLabel.text = audiofiles["filetitle"] <-line producing error
```

I believe I may have set the variables incorrectly, the value is being passed using segue from another tableview using the didSelectRowAt.

```
var audios = Array<Any>() <- gets from another controller
```

This is my current viewcontroller code:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var audioTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var descText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var clickButton: UIButton!

    var practitle = String()
    var desc = String()
    var hasAudio = Int()
    var audios = Array<Any>()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.title = practitle

        descText.text = desc

        if hasAudio != 0 {
            clickButton.isHidden = false
        }

        print(audios)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return audios.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "audiocell", for: indexPath) as! DetailViewCell

        let audiofiles = audios[indexPath.row]

        cell.audioLabel.text = audiofiles["filetitle"]

        return cell
    }
```

When I use

```
print(audios)
```

The result that I get is:

> [demoApp.Audiofile(id: 1, filetitle: "Sample file one", filename: "breath5mins", fileformat: "mp3"), demoApp.Audiofile(id: 2, filetitle: "Sample file two", filename: "breath10mins", fileformat: "mp3"), demoApp.Audiofile(id: 3, filetitle: "Sample file three", filename: "breath20mins", fileformat: "mp3")]

How can I use the filetitle as the label texts for my cell?

The goal is to display the title and open another view on cell click and allow the user to click a button on the new view and play the mp3 file.

Comment: What is the type of `demoApp.Audiofile(...)`?

Comment: Don't declare the array as `Array<Any>`. Declare it properly with the actual type it contains `Array<AudioFile>`.

Comment: i changed it but i get Use of undeclared type 'AudioFile' error for that line

Comment: @RonModz what does `type(of: demoApp.Audiofile(id: 1, filetitle: "Sample file one", filename: "breath5mins", fileformat: "mp3"))` print?

Comment: There was a typo in my comment; I typed `AudioFile` instead of `Audiofile` - My fingers automatically camelcased the type name to have an uppercase F

Comment: **P.S**: This is an array not a dictionary

Comment: @Carpsen90 yes i get Array<Any> when i did print type

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the object is **not** a *Swift dictionary*, it's a custom class or struct.

You are fighting Swift's strong type system. **Don't do that**.

Declare `audios` with the **static** type

```
var audios = Array<AudioFile>()
```

and use dot notation instead of insecure KVC (which does not work anyway in this case).

```
cell.audioLabel.text = audiofiles.filetitle
```

Comment: i made the changes but i get - Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: The crash cannot be related to this code. We are dealing with non-optionals.

Comment: @RonModz Take a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu) - You probably haven't connected an outlet between your storyboard and class.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared your array as `Array<Any>` - which means that the array can contain *anything*; the elements of the array don't even all need to be the same type.  As a result, the Swift compiler doesn't know what type of thing it is getting from `audios[indexPath.row]`; it could be a dictionary, it could be an array or it could be an integer.  When you try and use subscripting, the compiler gives you an error because it doesn't know whether the item *supports subscripting* - i.e. an `Int` doesn't, and `Any` could be an `Int`.

Don't use `Any` or `AnyObject` in Swift if you know the actual type; Swift's type safety allows it to eliminate a large number of potential runtime issues at compile time by know what types things are.

From the `print` statement it appears that your array contains `Audiofile` instances (presumably a struct or class you have defined, not a dictionary).  You should, therefore, declare `audios` correctly:

```
var audios = Array<Audiofile>()
```

You can then access the object's properties in your `cellForRow`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "audiocell", for: indexPath) as! DetailViewCell

    let audiofiles = audios[indexPath.row]

    cell.audioLabel.text = audiofiles.filetitle

    return cell
}
```

Comment: `type(of: demoApp.Audiofile(id: 1, filetitle: "Sample file one", filename: "breath5mins", fileformat: "mp3"))` is `Array<Any>`, maybe recommend declaring a `struct Audiofile`

Comment: The OP has an array of three elements. Those elements are `Audiofile`s (whatever that is, presumably a struct or class)

Comment: See the last comments under the question

Comment: Yes, because they are printing the details of the property in their receiving object, which they have declared as `Array<Any>`, so that is what Swift shows when they print `audios` .  What they *sent* to this class was an `Array<Audiofile>`. They need to fix the typing on the receiver property as I explained.  They already have the struct, they are just "losing" it by using `Any`

Comment: `demoApp.Audiofile(...)` in itself is `Array<Any>`

Comment: No, it's not.  You are suggesting that `audios` is *actually* `[[Any]]`, but you don't have key-value pairs in an array.

Comment: The OP says that `type(of: demoApp.Audiofile(...))` gives them `Array<Any>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179770/discussion-between-paulw11-and-carpsen90).

Answer (score -1):

The reason you get the error is `Any` is an object with no definition. You can cast it into an `AudioFile` like this:

```
let audiofiles = audios[indexPath.row] as! AudioFile
```

If `audios` is an array of `AudioFile` only then declare it as such and you can use it the way you described.

Comment: You will need a conditional or forced downcast there; you can't use a simple downcast from `Any` to `Audiofile`; it is better, however, to eliminate the use of `Any` altogether.